# svc service that can recieve any request

Tags: wcf, biztalk, svc, biztalk-2013r2

Hello BizTalk and WCF experts

I need your help todo a implementation for this scenario:

I have created a BizTalk application without schemas, orchestrations but just with a send port pipeline that look at the soap action on the request message and send the request to the correct destination service.
I have also created a in-process WCF-Custom receive port that my send port subscribe and I have defined following in-process custom URL "http://localhost:8080/bts/services/serviceRoute.svc".

Instead of calling the above metioned URL i want an IIS service endpoint that receive all the request and send it to ny custom url.

So i want a IIS svc endpoint without specific schema but a service endpoint that can receive any request no matter operationsname and send the request to my BizTalk receive port (my WCF-Custom receive port).

Can anyone tell me how I can define/create a IIS service endpoint for this scenario  or any other way I can solve this issue.?

Thanks for your help..

Answer (score 2):

Very important point: BizTalk already does this.  You don't need the extra IIS service.

BizTalk Receive Locations are not Schema bound.  They will happily accept any message type.  The only validation happens if you implement it.

So, I would start with a plain WCF-WebHttp endpoint hosted In-Process or IIS or WCF-BasicHttp/basicHttpBinding to have the Action automatically Promoted (IIRC, been a while ;).

You can configure the URL, security and what not any way you need in IIS.

Answer (score 1):

Create a service with a method that receives a [System.ServiceModel.Channels.Message](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.servicemodel.channels.message?view=netframework-4.7.2) class, like this interface:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://yournamespace")]
public interface IRouter
{
    [OperationContract(Action = "*", ReplyAction = "*", Name = "*")]
    [WebGet]
    Message RouteMessage(Message incomingRequest);
}
```

This will receive any message, including non-soap messages, so you can create your routing logic.
`Message` class has some useful members, like `Headers` property and `CreateMessage` method, that you can use to create a copy of original message and redirect to its destination, or simply extract the data for logging.

**EDIT**: *adding some information (some doubts in comments)*
Using the code above, you can simply redirect the incomming message to another endpoint, like this:

```
/* "endpointConfigurationName" is the name of a client endpoint, that is in Web.config, like this for instance:
<endpoint name="endpointConfigurationName" binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="someBindingConfiguration" behaviorConfiguration="someBehaviorConfiguration" contract="IRouter" />
notice that there is not an address defined, you can define in code */

using (var factory = new ChannelFactory<IRouter>("endpointConfigurationName", new EndpointAddress("http://destinationEndpoint")))
{
    // create a channel to send the resquest 
    IRouter router = factory.CreateChannel();
    // get the response
    var reply = router.ProcessarMensagem(incomingRequest);
}
```

This is a very simple example, but contains the base logic.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and sample. But i do not want to implement my own router but as i mentioned i want my reveive port to listen to a iis service endpoint that can receive any request. Can you give me a sample of that implementation!

Comment: Can i use your routing sample if it’s a request-response service?

Comment: @Balatharan For clarity, if you're using BizTalk, you do not need to do this.  BizTalk is the routing service.